# How do I add a highlight to a TabItem label in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I have a `TabView` with custom icons - like this:

```swift
    PastView( settings ).tabItem 
    {
        Image("past")
        Text("Past")
    }.tag(1)
```

which works great - but just the text changing color is very subtle - it's not obvious which tab is "current".    I want to make it much more obvious by doing something to the image.  I've tried all of thse

```swift
      Image("past").shadow( radius:5 )
      Image("past").border( Color.red, width:8 )
      Image("past").background( Color.green )
```

but none of them have any effect at all - and I don't really understand why

Answer (score 0):

try adding ".accentColor(.red)" to the TabView.

Comment: accent color was already working (as mentioned above) - the text changes color fine - I want to do something to _the image_ (and it's not a systemimage)

Comment: my bad of course, I did not see you mentioning accentColor.

Answer (score 0):

`TabItem` image in SwiftUI has very limited customization at present.  Even in `UIKit` you would be making those changes to the `ImageView` container not the Image itself.

Design selected and unselected versions of your icons, and then use them as below.  You may also want to create different versions of the icons in the Asset Catalog for dark mode.

```
@State private var selectedTab = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            ViewA()
                .tabItem {
                    selectedTab == 0 ? Image("past-selected") : Image("past-unselected")
                }.tag(0)
            
            ViewB()
                .tabItem {
                    selectedTab == 1 ? // etc ...
                }.tag(1)
        }
    }
```